# ¿Cómo hago una consulta donde solo obtenga una sola vez mi ID usando SQL?

Tags: sql

Lo que me gustaría realizar es poder hacer una consulta que me obtenga una sola vez mi `ID` foraneo que en esta caso es de una empresa, quiero que me obtenga todos los ID foraneos mi consulta pero que los que estén repetidos solo me los tome una sola vez, sin necesidad de repetirlos.

Código de la consulta:

```
SELECT
      *
  FROM [DBSIADANA].[dbo].[v_Autorizaciones]
  GROUP BY
    Empresa
  HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
GO
```

Error:

> Column 'DBSIADANA.dbo.v_Autorizaciones.certificado' is invalid in the
>   select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: lo que quieres es listar todas las "Empresa" sin repetirse ?

Comment: si, eso es correcto

Comment: si la respuesta de @w33haa agradecería que la aceptes :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando como base tu consulta, la modificaría de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT
    Empresa, Campo1, Campo 2
FROM [DBSIADANA].[dbo].[v_Autorizaciones]
GROUP BY
    Empresa, Campo1, Campo 2
```

Al utilizar `GROUP BY` el manejador de la base de datos te obliga a agrupar todos aquellos campos que deseas mostrar en la consulta, por tal motivo te muestra ese error, esto se traduce a que para este caso, los campos que desees mostrar los tienes que agrupar para que no te envíe el error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Empresa
FROM [DBSIADANA].[dbo].[v_Autorizaciones]
```